# How to insert few lines in between of another file

Tags: batch-file

I have one Input file that I am going to use as a reference file (OR as a template).

***Template.txt***

```
blah blah blah - line 1
blah blah blah - line 2
blah blah blah - line n
# Begin Source Files
FILE = <Enter The path of all the source files mentioned in TEMP.txt file>
# End Source Files
```

Again many more lines

***Temp.txt***

```
// This file only contains path of src files
D:\Myproject\src\a.cpp
D:\Myproject\src\b.cpp
D:\Myproject\src\c.cpp
D:\Myproject\src\d.cpp
```

Now, I need to use this `template.txt` file and need to produce my output file something like this (`output.txt`):

```
blah blah blah - line 1
blah blah blah - line 2
blah blah blah - line n
# Begin Source Files
FILE = D:\Myproject\src\a.cpp
FILE = D:\Myproject\src\b.cpp
FILE = D:\Myproject\src\c.cpp
FILE = D:\Myproject\src\d.cpp
# End Source Files
```

Again many more lines

I don't know how to insert the source file paths(which are present in `temp.txt` into the middle of `output.txt`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `FOR` command to do this ...

```
FOR /F %%i IN (Temp.txt) ECHO FILE  = %i > dest
```

You may have to work on the syntax ... I am typing this on a Mac machine purely fro my memory

```
FOR /F loops through individual lines in a text file
```

Comment: thanks for fixing the formatting ... sorry about posting the code without proper formatting